# Plumbing vent question

Tags: plumbing

Can someone tell me if this plumbing is acceptable?  Looks like some type of vent. I am plumbing newb. [image: sink] [image: bath tub]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an air admittance valve (AAV).  They are allowed in some areas.  You'd have to check with local building codes, to know if they're allowed where you are.  Your local building department should be able to tell you, but I would suspect they are allowed (unless the plumbing was installed by an amatuer).

Comment: Does it require any maintenance ?

Comment: Also I don’t see how air is being admitted in - especially the bottom example

Comment: @ecco88 the second image is a "*drum trap*".  Sorry I didn't realize you were asking about both fittings.